# unable to find tinymce 4.0.8 autocomplete plugin

Tags: tinymce-4

I am using tinymce 4.0.8 for my website. The older version of tinymce is having autocomplete plugin but for this version i am unable to find any plugin for auto complete. Can any one know how can i get that plugin for **4.0.8 version**.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using a custom plugin. Autocomplete does not ship with TinyMCE.

Here's the list of available plugins in 4.x:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugins

And here's the list that were removed in the 3->4 upgrade:

```
These plugins where removed in 4.0: advhr, advimage, advlink, iespell, inlinepopups, style, emotions and xhtmlxtras.
```

[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial%3aMigration_guide_from_3.x)

So, make sure the thirdparty plugin has been ported to 4.x and that you made it available in the plugins directory.